# Config file for python

Tags: python, config

Iam quite new to python, Iam trying to make a script and have some config file with some setting (like DB hosts, user and password or API URL ect..). But I got stuck on one thing:

I search for users in two different parts of the main script, in one place the user is identified just by name like "JohnB" and in the other its identified by ID like "34". What I need is somehow connect the right output depending on the fact if its exact name or id (so somehow know that JohnB and 34 is the same thing). The dict() is probably not good for this. Any ideas what shloud I use?

Basically in the first case Iam calling one URL to get a file with few lines. From this file I only parse the name (because there's not much else there anyway) so lets say I have variable "name" with stored name of user. In the second case Iam selecting the DB for events and each event may have a user. This user is just ID. Now IF the event have a user (like user 34 which is for example JohnB) I want to add specific hash to variable "user" but IF the event have no user which can happend I want to tag (use the hash) of user from that parsed file.

So far I had two IF conditions on two places in my code (without using the conf.py file) and it looked like this: `if name == "JohnB": user=5@RuZg67A`  and in that second part of code when I go through the result from mysql select `if x[8] == 34:  user=5@RuZg67A`

Comment: Welcome to `SO`. You question is well-formed, albeit without any code snippets. Can you provide these so that we can be of further help?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the code in question.

Comment: Please refer this article for initial understanding: https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/